# htaccess not working for any URI besides empty

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

When I visit my site as `example.com` I get redirected properly to `example.com/language/` (based on the language). But, whenever I request `example.com/page` it will 404 and will not redirect me to `example.com/language/page`

These are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/pt%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(en|pt|es)/ $1/index.php [L]
```

As for my folder structure I have:

```
...
.htaccess
en
  pages
es
  pages
pt
  pages
```

Any help is appreaciated. Thank you.